# Why can't I see ROS 2 topics from systemd service when using a Fast DDS server with UDP transport?

Tags: ros, ros2, distributed-systems, fastdds

I would like to communicate with ROS nodes running in a systemd service. Multicast discovery and shared memory transport cannot be used in this context, so I'm using a discovery server and UDP transport instead.

I have a [Fast DDS discovery server](https://%20https://eprosima-discovery-server.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) with the following configuration (`@guidPrefix@` and `@port@` are replaced during system setup):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<profiles xmlns="http://www.eprosima.com/XMLSchemas/fastRTPS_Profiles">
    <participant profile_name="server" is_default_profile="true">
        <rtps>
            <prefix>@guidPrefix@</prefix>
            <builtin>
                <discovery_config>
                    <discoveryProtocol>SERVER</discoveryProtocol>
                </discovery_config>
                <metatrafficUnicastLocatorList>
                    <locator>
                        <udpv4>
                            <address>0.0.0.0</address>
                            <port>@port@</port>
                        </udpv4>
                    </locator>
                </metatrafficUnicastLocatorList>
            </builtin>
        </rtps>
    </participant>
</profiles>
```

The ROS daemon and nodes are launched with the following configuration:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<profiles xmlns="http://www.eprosima.com/XMLSchemas/fastRTPS_Profiles">
    <transport_descriptors>
        <transport_descriptor>
            <transport_id>udp_transport</transport_id>
            <type>UDPv4</type>
        </transport_descriptor>
    </transport_descriptors>
    <participant profile_name="participant_profile_ros2" is_default_profile="true">
        <rtps>
            <name>profile_for_ros2_context</name>
            <useBuiltinTransports>false</useBuiltinTransports>
            <userTransports>
                <transport_id>udp_transport</transport_id>
            </userTransports>
            <builtin>
                <discovery_config>
                    <discoveryProtocol>CLIENT</discoveryProtocol>
                    <discoveryServersList>
                        <RemoteServer prefix="@guidPrefix@">
                            <metatrafficUnicastLocatorList>
                                <locator>
                                    <udpv4>
                                        <address>127.0.0.1</address>
                                        <port>@port@</port>
                                    </udpv4>
                                </locator>
                            </metatrafficUnicastLocatorList>
                        </RemoteServer>
                    </discoveryServersList>
                </discovery_config>
            </builtin>
        </rtps>
    </participant>
</profiles>
```

When I run `ros2 topic list`, I cannot see any of the topics from the systemd service. Why?

Answer (score 1):

The ROS 2 CLI tools (or the daemon, if it is in use) must be `SUPER_CLIENT`s, as they rely on additional discovery information.

See:

- [The Fast DDS documentation on discovery servers and ROS 2 introspection](https://fast-dds.docs.eprosima.com/en/latest/fastdds/ros2/discovery_server/ros2_discovery_server.html#ros-2-introspection)
- [A similar problem discussed on the ROS 2 Discourse instance](https://discourse.ros.org/t/discovery-problems-with-the-discovery-server/19900)